# Finding the general solution of the differential equation $y' = xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of the differential equation: $y' = xy$.

Disagreeing with my friend on this, what's your take?

Comment: Is this a trick to make us spit out the answer?

Comment: Show us your work or tell us your thoughts.

Comment: This is what I have so far.y'=dy/dx=xy
1/ydy=xdx
integrate 
logy=1/2x^2+c
y=e^(1/2x^2+c)
=Ae^(1/2x^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to this ODE is $y(x)=C e^\frac{x^2}{2}$. This solution can be found using separation of variables.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-xy$$

$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=-x        $$

$$\frac{1}{y}dy=-x dx \iff \int\frac{1}{y}=\int-x$$

$$\ln (y)+c=\frac{-(x^2)}{2} +c$$

$$2\ln(y)+c=-x^2+c$$

$$\ln y^2 = x^2 + c \iff y^2 = Ce^{x^2}\iff y = ce^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: The minus sign in your first equation disagrees with the Question being asked above.  Fortuitously the sign suddenly disappears when the last line of reasoning is reached.

Comment: Odd timing + wrong answer = 2 upvotes? Life is good.

Comment: someone edited this but didnt say why they took out the minus sign

Comment: and sorry i misread the question